# How to style an Image Field button in Django App

Tags: css, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I want to style my Image Field Button (Choose File) with CSS. Currently, its displaying in the default theme. I am using Bootstrap V5.0.1, Django V3.2.12, Python 3.7.6.

[image: Default Image Field Button]

First, I tried to identify or add a class or id which I can add and style the button regularly but was unable to add as the button was added by Django Image Field. The Code in my forms.py is given below:

```
from django import forms
class ImageUploadForm(forms.Form):
   image = forms.ImageField(label='')
```

Then I used the Hover functionality of the Chrome Developer Tools to identify any leads and found that the button and its area had 2 id's #file-upload-button and #id_image.

[image]
[image]

I tried to add CSS to the above-mentioned id's but did not get the result i desired. I want to style the Choose File Button Below also if possible can i add any bootstrap to the button, any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

[image]

HTML-Django Code

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<br>
<button type="submit" id="btnUpload" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:20px;">Upload</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem and came upon this article https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

The ideia is to create a useless button and add style to it, then overlap both with the image field button on top, and then set the opacity of the image button to 0.

The image field button will still work, but you will only see the button with the style you add.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).